# Data recovery on MBP 15’s SSD corrupted drive?

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, ssd, data-recovery, file-recovery

It seems like I’ve used up all space on my MBP, and when I rebooted it it became corrupted/inoperable (when I go into disk utilities, Macintosh HD is “unmounted”, and when I press “mount”, nothing happens. On internet recovery, the same thing gives me “Alert: couldn’t mount disk”. Clicking “Repair” gives me “Alert: Partition map repair failed while adjusting structures to fit current whole disk size.”)

I was wondering if it’s possible to recover any data from it? I have some sensitive documents that haven’t backed up due to poor internet connection. On disk utility it says the drive could not be mounted and I can’t find the drive via the terminal.

Thank you!

Comment: Using up all your space should not normally cause the drive to become completely inoperable. So something else has happened. Unfortunately, SSDs are much harder to recover than HDDs. If you had FileVault on, even more so.

Answer (score 0):

Is your drive formatted as an **HFS+** (**macOS Extended**) or **APFS** volume? If it’s HFS+, you can try **[DiskWarrior](https://www.alsoft.com/)**. (Though, from the sound of it, the corruption may not be in the volume itself but rather in the partition map, and I don’t know if DiskWarrior is able to fix those errors. May be worth reaching out to their [support team](https://www.alsoft.com/support-form).)

Answer (score 0):

Sure, all Mac hardware  boots easily from external drives.

Worst case, you take a suitable drive for your Mac to another, get an OS installed and then connect it to the failed system. Best case, you can boot to internet recovery from the failed Mac and install an OS on to the connected drive and finish the setup without outside assistance.

From there, Data Rescue is the first tool I would take to see about data recovery. Others exist, but that specializes in recovery so start there first.